# Rails & Capistrano - Deployment gem issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

I've frozen my gems locally, and commit them in latest git version.  I pushed this to my production server, and my capfile automatically pulls this when deploying (via locally stored git).

Now the issue I run into is that even though I know the server has the gem installed, when I deploy using "cap deploy:cold", I get the following error:

```
*** [err :: domain.com] Missing these required gems:
*** [err :: domain.com] RedCloth
*** [err :: domain.com] 
*** [err :: domain.com] You're running:
*** [err :: domain.com] ruby 1.8.7.174 at /usr/bin/ruby1.8
*** [err :: domain.com] rubygems 1.3.5 at /home/user/.gem/ruby/1.8, /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
*** [err :: domain.com] 
*** [err :: domain.com] Run `rake gems:install` to install the missing gems.
```

Should I run rake gems:install in the latest release?  When I do this nothing happens.  Am I supposed to do rake gems:build somewhere; in my capfile?  I do this in the latest release via console and in that directory and I do not get notices that anything was built, but I probably don't understand that function to begin with.

What am I missing?

Note. When I run gem list, I do see the gem install on the production server.

Answer (score 0):

Because you say `gem list` includes RedCloth, the problem should be elsewhere.

How do you include the Gem in your application?
RedCloth is a bit unconventional. The name of the gem is CamelCase while the main file is lowercase.

For this reason, you should specify the `:lib` option.

```
config.gem "RedCloth", :lib => "redcloth"
```

Comment: That didn't seem to work, but I'm just going to exclude it from the app for now.  It's causing too much of a headache.